# MPDF full page background

Tags: mpdf

I spent way too much time on this and I can't figure out a good 21th century solution.

Simply I have to generate a business card in PDF with a background image, but MPDF isn't very helpful.

By default I had:

```
@page{
    sheet-size: 90mm 55mm;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I tried to:

- use @page{ background-size: 100%; } `doesn't work`
- use @page{ background-size: cover; } `doesn't work`
- resize the image - even if I set the right size in 'mm', it will be smaller or larger, even if I set the **background-image-resolution** to the same value as the image.
- place **absolute** positioned `div` with background image
- same but with `img` tags, using `src` attribute.

At the last option, I've got a really strange thing. It showed the whole image but in a small rectangle in the pages, but not even in full height.

**Does anyone have an idea, how to simply use an image as a page background?**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

mPDF has a custom css property for background images: background-image-resize with custom values from 0-6:

- 0 - No resizing (default)
- 1 - Shrink-to-fit w (keep aspect ratio)
- 2 - Shrink-to-fit h (keep aspect ratio)
- 3 - Shrink-to-fit w and/or h (keep aspect ratio)
- 4 - Resize-to-fit w (keep aspect ratio)
- 5 - Resize-to-fit h (keep aspect ratio)
- 6 - Resize-to-fit w and h

So you probably need:
body {background-image:url(something.png); background-image-resize:6}

[Taken from mPDF docs](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html)

Comment: That is working, if you want to have the image on every page. Any ideas how to stretch it only for a single page? In my project, only on some pages there are full page images and its not always the same.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution yourself. Just posting the link for others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860714/mpdf-full-page-size-image-but-only-for-single-page/39876357

Answer (score 4):

Working example with the `background-image-resolution` property :

```
<body style="background-image: url('/absolute/path/to/image.jpg');
             background-position: top left;
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             background-image-resize: 4;
             background-image-resolution: from-image;">
```

It works fine with a 300DPI JPEG picture on invoices.

> if you use **both the `style="..."` tag and a `body{...}` style in CSS**, mpdf will ignore the `style="..."` tag and its content, so the picture will not appear!

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else needs a background-cover in mPDF and is not helped by background-image-resize, which breaks as soon as it is wrapped by a floated element. Floated elements are often necessary within mPdf because of the abscence of css compliance. Here is a more robust solution for a circled image, with bg-cover simulated.

**Get image orientation**

```
function getImageOrientation(string $imgPath){

  list($imgWidth,$imgHeight) = getimagesize($imgPath);

  $aspectRatio = $imgWidth / $imgHeight;

  if($aspectRatio >= 1){
      return array('landscape',$imgWidth,$imgHeight,$aspectRatio);
  }else{
      return array('portrait',$imgWidth,$imgHeight,$aspectRatio);
  }
```

}

**Set own properties to simulate background-cover**

```
public static function returnCircledImage($imgPath, int $size){

    list($orientation,$imgWidth,$imgHeight, $aspectRatio) = getImageOrientation($imgPath);

    if($orientation == 'landscape'){
        $backgroundSize = 'auto 100%'; //fit height, keep aspect ratio
        $calculatedWidth = floor($size * $aspectRatio);
        $calculatedHeight = $size;

        //position center manually
        $dx = -floor(($calculatedWidth - $calculatedHeight) / 2);
        $dy = 0;
    }else{
        $backgroundSize = '100% auto'; //fit width, keep aspect ratio
        $calculatedWidth = $size;
        $calculatedHeight = floor($size * $aspectRatio);

        //position center manually
        $dx = 0;
        $dy = -floor(($calculatedHeight - $calculatedWidth) / 2);
    }

    return sprintf('

        <div class="%s" style="background-size: %s; background-position:%spx %spx; overflow:hidden; border-radius:100px; width:%spx; height:%spx; background-image: url(%s)"></div>

        ',
        $backgroundSize,
        $dx,
        $dy,
        $size,
        $size,
        $imgPath
    );
}
```