# MPdf - Full page size image, but only for single page

Tags: mpdf

I know there are similar questions, but non of them solve my problem. What i want to do with mPDF is the following:

```
Page 1: Text for item 1
Page 2: Full width and height image to cover the page with an image of item 1
Page 3: Text for item 2
Page 4: Full width and height image to cover the page with an image of item 2
...
```

The following code stretches an image in the way, I want to achieve:

```
    body {
        background-image:url("image1.jpg");
        background-image-resize: 5;
        background-position: top center;
    }
```

But this results to set the image on EVERY page (i know, its the body element). So i tried the following:

```
<div style='
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image:url("image1.jpg");
        background-image-resize: 5;
        background-position: top center;
    '></div>
```

But that is not working. So i tried the same code, just with an color, instead an image:

```
    <div style='
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #F00;
        '>
    </div>
    <div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
```

And this is working. The whole page is red. So how to achive the same with an image?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

After a lot of tryouts, I found out, that the easist way to do this, is just to split up the HTML code into separate parts and insert them with separate WriteHtml calls. For example:

```
// Create object
$mpdf = new \mPDF('utf-8');

// Create first text page
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Text for item 1</p>');

// Add a new page with the image
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->WriteHTML("<html><body style='background-image:url(\"image1.jpg\"); background-image-resize: 5; background-position: top center;'></body></html>");


// Create second page
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Text for item 1</p>');

...
```

Comment: This is a very solution. If you are building a PDF via HTML, bear in mind that you can't apply `height` on a lot of element, especially `table`s where you could've done `vertical-align:middle`. The trick here is to create a `<div style="height:100%">` with a background-image, position it `center` with `no-repeat`, and voila.

Answer (score 2):

**Size constraint** :
When writing HTML, image size is automatically constrained to current margins and page position. An extra parameter added to end of the Image() function allows you to override this:

```
<?php
// the last "false" allows a full page picture
$mpdf->Image('files/images/frontcover.jpg', 0, 0, 210, 297, 'jpg', '', true, false);
```

This is useful for e.g. a cover page for your document.

This can be achieved using HTML and CSS like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left:0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;">
    <img src="/files/images/frontcover.jpg" 
         style="width: 210mm; height: 297mm; margin: 0;" />
</div>
```

See https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/images.html#size-constraint for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried [Sunchock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9586195/sunchock) answer and didn't worked for me as is, but with some modifications I've finally created a full image cover (first PDF page).

Here is the code. Basically I removed the `img` tag and moved the size style to the div. Finally in the style of the html (maybe could be as inline style in the div) added the image as background. You can find more info about `background-image-resize` tag in mpdf doc [here](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html)

```
<style>
#cover {
  background-image: url("http://php72.com/resources/image.png");
  background-image-resize: 6;
}
</style>

<div id="cover" style="position: absolute; left:0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 210mm; height: 297mm;">
</div>
```